# UIProgressView on UIButton to display downloading status iOS5

Tags: ios5, queue, nsurlconnection, uiprogressview

I am developing one iphone app using iOS 5. I want to implement the functionality like kindle app to download data from server as shown in following image

[image]

I have implemented the progress view on button. Nut when I scroll the table cell , progress is not synched with the current progress. When I scroll the table it shows progress as 0.0

Also how can I queue the request & start one after the previous request is complete ?
How can I delete the particular request when user clicks on Cross button ?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.